# Finding out the number of solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

If $a,b,c$ are three distinct real numbers for which there exists $x,y,z$ such that $$x+y+z=1$$$$ax+by+cz=t$$$$a^2x+b^2y+c^2z=t^2$$then $a^3x+b^3y+c^3z-t^3=P(t)$,be a polynomial in $t$,then the question is to find out the number of solutions to P(t)=0 .

My attempt at the solution

We are given three equations.From there we can solve for $x,y,z$ using Cramer's rule.by solving I got $$x=\frac{(t-b)(b-c)(c-t)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}$$  $$y=\frac{(a-t)(c-a)(t-c)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}$$    $$z=\frac{(a-b)(b-t)(t-a)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}$$  however plugging it in the equation I got $$P(t)=a^3( t-b)(b-c)(c-t)+b^3 (a-t)(c-a)(t-c)+c^3 (a-b)(b-t)(t-a)-t^3(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)=0$$ from here I couldn't proceed.please help me in this regard.thanks.

Comment: Are $x,y,z$ integers?

Comment: Number of solutions = degree of the polynomial!

Comment: @AlexSilva but how do you know that there isn't only one real solution?

Comment: The OP is not asking for  real solutions of $P(t)$. Why not complex ones?.

Comment: @AlexSilva I am looking for real solutions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde x,y,z are reals.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Now just simply observe that $P(a)=0$ and $P(b)=0$ and $P(c)=0$

Well just plug in $x,y,z$ respectively...

So when you calculate $P(a)$, you will find that $y,z$ simply vanish and $x=1$.
Hence it is a root...

Comment: $P(a)$ is not zero. There is no $(a-t)$ term in the first term of the polynomial.

Comment: Either I am making some blunder or the OP as made a grave error in writing the expression of $P(t)$ in his attempt.

Comment: @navinstudent take a relook at your expression for P(t), you just didn't right the denominators everywhere (or at least multiply $t^3$ by $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$. Try writing it correctly and go through what I have written again, it should be obvious to you then.

Comment: Oh yes sorry for that.

Answer (score -1):

you are given $a^{3}x+b^{3}y+c^{3}z−t^{3}=P(t)$.Equate $P(t)=0$.Then multiply $(a+b+c)$ on both sides and then simplify to get
$t^{3}-(a+b+c)t^{2}+(ab+bc+ca)t-abc=0 $ which shows that the roots are $a,b,c$.